# How to open more than two word txt file in cmd

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

I have a text file "English word.txt" in local disk D. I tried to open this file using following command in command prompt in Windows xp

D:>English word.txt

but it didn't work and following message was there

'English' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

if any one can provide solution for this, it will be useful for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in quote marks.

For example:

```
D:>"English word.txt"
```

The reason for this not working as you want is the white space! So encapsulating it in quote marks tells provides the entire path!

If your file was one word like

```
D:>EnglishWord.txt
```

then it would run with or without quote marks

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding your command with quotation marks:

`D:>"English word.txt"`